# How to calculate time difference in PHP and store the time difference in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in the database with the name `attendance`. It has three columns: `intime`, `outtime` and `work_hours`.
I have date and time in `intime` and `outime`. Now I want to write the php code to calculate the time difference in the format `hh:mm:ss` to store into the column `work_hour` of `attendance` table.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`timediff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) returns the difference between two `datetime`s as a `time` value:

```
UPDATE attendance
SET    work_hours = TIMEDIFF (outtime, intime)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one simple solution, but you will find better. Just try this.
For this you need to convert both of your outtime and intime in seconds using

```
$working_time_in_seconds = strtotime($outtime) - strtotime($intime);

echo date('H:i:s', $working_time_in_seconds );
```